# Failed to execute SSIS package in SQL Job

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a simple SSIS package that only has 2 steps. Step 1 is a script task that will return the creation date of the last created file in the specific folder. And the second step, it will save the step 1 data into the database. Here is the complete code for step 1 in C#.

```
string vDir = Dts.Variables["UnitDirectory"].Value.ToString();
string vDBName = Dts.Variables["DatabaseName"].Value.ToString();

var directory = new DirectoryInfo(vDir);
var myFile = directory.GetFiles(vDBName + "*").OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();

DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(vDir + myFile);

Dts.Variables["CreatedDate"].Value = creation;
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

In this case, i pass UnitDirectory variable with network sharing directory.

```
\\192.168.0.2\Database Backup\
```

The problem is, I can execute this package both from the Integration Service Catalog in SQL Server Management Studio and from Visual Studio. But, when I executed it as SQL Job, it just errors in step 1 and giving an unclear message.

```
Script Task:Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I run SQL Job with my domain administrator credentials which have login access into network sharing directory. And this problem starts when I run in new installed SQL Server 2014. Previously this package has run normally in my old SQL Server.

Can you give me solution for this? I need your solution based on your experience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Agent job is almost definitely running as a different user. Check which user the SQL Agent is running as (it says it in the SQL Agent job log). The default user doesn't have access to mapped drives

Comment: Yes. try to add a database credential object of the user that runs your Management Studio and create a SQL Agent Proxy with that credential and change the SQL Agent steps to that proxy user.

Comment: @abbgrade ok, i'll try to create credentials and proxy

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i've change the default one (NT Service\SQLServerAgent) as new user which has access to mapped drives though.

Comment: Did you restart the SQL Agent? Anyway you would probably get a more useful error message of you just did this in Powershell. SSIS is really overcomplicated to do what you want to do, and by default the script task does not show useful errors

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid After change service account it will restart the SQL Agent automatically. Exactly, i've change my main focus now, which is to show the main error reason in SSIS script task.